# Instantiate a Imagick object using a file that exists

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to get the first page of a .pdf and convert it to a `.jpg`. So this is my initial code:

```
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . '.jpg';
    $file->move('catalogues', $filename); 
    $this->setFileName($filename);

    $im = new \Imagick('/catalogues/' . $filename);
    die("here I die");
```

The problem: I get this error:

> unable to open image
>   `/catalogues/0cd10cccf88d80295eba12ef56423f9184dde1c4.jpg': No such
>   file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638

I can not understand it, since I have the file at `docuement_root/catalogues/0cd10cccf88d80295eba12ef56423f9184dde1c4.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your `document_root` folder is actual site root directory.